# Redirect add to cart url if user tries to add to cart a WooCommerce Subscription (all variations) that they already have?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect

I have a link like: https://example.com/checkout/?add_to_cart=1&variation_id=2

The option to Limit Subscriptions to just one active subscription is on (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/#limit-subscription)

When a user with an active subscription who is logged in clicks that add to cart link, at the moment it ends up on the “cart” page with the following error: “Sorry, this product cannot be purchased”

Instead of this, I’d like the user to be redirect to the product page (where they can switch between subscription variations): https://example.com/product/subscription

Please help me achieve this. I’ve tried to hook into cart validation, use template redirects, hook into the checkout page, none of the options work. I still get redirected to the cart page, with the error above listed.